# Updating state of widget from another widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I have been writing a Sorting visualiser in `flutter`, I am so far able to animate the movement of blocks. But I also want to update the colours of the block, when the block goes through the states of being scanned, moved, and finally when it is completely sorted. I looked up the `State management` in flutter, and it is rather confusing to know what approach should I be using in my project.
 Below is the `DashBoard Class`:

```
import 'package:algolizer/sortingAlgorithms/Block.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class DashBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  double width;
  double height;
  DashBoard(@required this.width, @required this.height);
  @override
  _DashBoardState createState() => _DashBoardState();
}

class _DashBoardState extends State<DashBoard> {
  double currentSliderValue = 50;
  List<double> arr = new List(500);
  List<Block> blockList;
  bool running = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fillArr((widget.width * 0.6) / 50, (widget.width * 0.1) / 50,
        widget.height * 0.7);
  }

  void InsertionSort() async {
    setState(() {
      running = true;
    });
    int delay = (pow(15, 4) / pow(currentSliderValue, 2)).round();
    for (int i = 1; i < currentSliderValue; i++) {
      if (blockList[i] == null) break;
      Block key = blockList[i];
      int j = i - 1;
      while (j >= 0 && blockList[j].height > key.height) {
        setState(() {
          blockList[j + 1] = blockList[j];
        });
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delay));
        j--;
      }
      blockList[j + 1] = key;
    }
    setState(() {
      running = false;
    });
  }

  void BubbleSort() async {
    setState(() {
      running = true;
    });
    int delay = (pow(15, 4) / pow(currentSliderValue, 2)).round();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentSliderValue - 1; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < currentSliderValue - i - 1; j++) {
        if (blockList[j].height > blockList[j + 1].height) {
          Block temp = blockList[j + 1];
          setState(() {
            blockList[j + 1] = blockList[j];
            blockList[j] = temp;
          });
          await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delay));
        }
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      running = false;
    });
  }

  // Map<String, >
  void fillArr(double width, double margin, double height) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arr[i] = null;
    var rng = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentSliderValue; i++) {
      double val = rng.nextDouble() * height;
      if (val == 0)
        continue;
      else
        arr[i] = val;
    }
    blockList = [...arr.map((height) => Block(height, width, margin))];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              children: [
                      Text(
                        "Length",
                      ),
                      Slider(
                          value: currentSliderValue,
                          min: 5,
                          max: 200,
                          onChanged: (double value) {
                            setState(() {
                              currentSliderValue = value;
                            });
                            double newwidth =
                                (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6) /
                                    currentSliderValue;
                            double newmargin =
                                (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1) /
                                    currentSliderValue;

                            fillArr(newwidth, newmargin, widget.height * 0.7);
                          }),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text("Insertion Sort"),
                        onPressed: InsertionSort,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: BubbleSort, child: Text("Bubble Sort")),
                      RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Merge Sort")),
                      RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Quick Sort")),
                      RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Counting Sort")),
                      RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Radix Sort")),
                      RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Selection Sort")),
                      RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Heap Sort")),
                    ],
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [...blockList],
            ),
            // Row(
            //   children: [
            //     Container(
            //     child: Row(children: [
            //       Text("Algorithm")
            //     ],)
            //   )]
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the `Block` class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Block extends StatefulWidget {
  Block(@required this.height, @required this.width, @required this.mar);
  double height;
  double width;
  double mar;
  @override
  _BlockState createState() => _BlockState();
}

class _BlockState extends State<Block> {
  Color col = Colors.blue;
  // void isKey() {
  //   setState(() {
  //     col = Colors.pink;
  //   });
  // }

  // void notKey() {
  //   setState(() {
  //     col = Colors.purple;
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (widget.height == null)
        ? Container()
        : Container(
            height: this.widget.height,
            width: widget.width,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(widget.mar),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: col,
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as which state management route to go with, it really can be done with any of them. [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) to me is the easiest and has the least boilerplate.

Here's one way to do this. I just updated the `insertionSort` method to get you started and you can go from there. Any other changes you notice in your other classes are just to get rid of linter errors.

All your methods and variables can now live in a GetX class. With the exception of `color`, the rest are now observable streams.

```
class BlockController extends GetxController {
  RxDouble currentSliderValue = 50.0.obs; // adding .obs makes variable obserable
  RxList arr = List(500).obs;
  RxList blockList = [].obs;
  RxBool running = false.obs;

  Color color = Colors.red;

  void insertionSort() async {
    running.value = true; // adding .value access the value of observable variable
    color = Colors.blue;
    int delay = (pow(15, 4) / pow(currentSliderValue.value, 2)).round();
    for (int i = 1; i < currentSliderValue.value; i++) {
      if (blockList[i] == null) break;
      Block key = blockList[i];
      int j = i - 1;
      while (j >= 0 && blockList[j].height > key.height) {
        blockList[j + 1] = blockList[j];
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delay));
        j--;
      }
      blockList[j + 1] = key;
    }
    color = Colors.green;
    update(); // only needed for the color property because its not an observable stream
    running.value = false;
  }

  void bubbleSort() async {
    running.value = true;
    int delay = (pow(15, 4) / pow(currentSliderValue.value, 2)).round();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentSliderValue.value - 1; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < currentSliderValue.value - i - 1; j++) {
        if (blockList[j].height > blockList[j + 1].height) {
          Block temp = blockList[j + 1];
          blockList[j + 1] = blockList[j];
          blockList[j] = temp;
          await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delay));
        }
      }
    }
    running.value = false;
  }

  // Map<String, >
  void fillArr(double width, double margin, double height) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arr[i] = null;
    var rng = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentSliderValue.value; i++) {
      double val = rng.nextDouble() * height;
      if (val == 0)
        continue;
      else
        arr[i] = val;
    }
    blockList = [...arr.map((height) => Block(height, width, margin))].obs;
  }
}
```

Initialize the controller in your main before running your app. Generally it can be done anywhere as long as its before you try to access the controller.

```
  Get.put(BlockController());
```

Here's your much less busy `DashBoard` now that all that logic is tucked away in a GetX class. Here we find the controller, and use it access all those variables and methods.

`Obx` is the GetX widget that rebuilds on changes.

```
class DashBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  DashBoard(this.width, this.height);
  @override
  _DashBoardState createState() => _DashBoardState();
}

class _DashBoardState extends State<DashBoard> {
  final controller = Get.find<BlockController>(); // finding same instance of BlockConroller that you initialized in `Main`

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller.fillArr((widget.width * 0.6) / 50, (widget.width * 0.1) / 50,
        widget.height * 0.7);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Obx(
              // rebuilds when observable variables change
              () => Column(
                // changed to Column because a Row was overflowing
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Length",
                  ),
                  Slider(
                      value: controller.currentSliderValue.value,
                      min: 5,
                      max: 200,
                      onChanged: (double value) {
                          controller.currentSliderValue.value = value;                   
                        double newwidth =
                            (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6) /
                                controller.currentSliderValue.value;
                        double newmargin =
                            (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1) /
                                controller.currentSliderValue.value;

                        controller.fillArr(
                            newwidth, newmargin, widget.height * 0.7);
                      }),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Insertion Sort"),
                    onPressed: controller.insertionSort,
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: controller.bubbleSort,
                      child: Text("Bubble Sort")),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Merge Sort")),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Quick Sort")),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Counting Sort")),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Radix Sort")),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Selection Sort")),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Heap Sort")),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Obx(
              // rebuilds when observable variables change
              () => Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [...controller.blockList],
              ),
            ),
            // Row(
            //   children: [
            //     Container(
            //     child: Row(children: [
            //       Text("Algorithm")
            //     ],)
            //   )]
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's your `Block` which can now be stateless. Key thing of note here is the `GetBuilder` widget that updates the color.

```
class Block extends StatelessWidget {
  // now can be stateless
  Block(this.height, this.width, this.mar);
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final double mar;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (height == null)
        ? Container()
        : GetBuilder<BlockController>(
            // triggers rebuilds when update() is called from GetX class
            builder: (controller) => Container(
              height: this.height,
              width: width,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(mar),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: controller.color,
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

[image]